# Is there software to copy existing music sheet?

Tags: piano, software, sheet-music, midi

Is there software that I can enter (kind of type) an existing music sheet and play it on the computer choosing piano for example?

Comment: Yamaha were developing one years ago that could read a scanned score. idk whatever happened to it but it might be worth a Google.

Answer (score 1):

Proprietary/Commercial: Finale, Sibelius

Free: MuseScore, Lilypond

Finale can import scanned scores.

MuseScore is acceptable for small projects, but for larger ones you should probably buy software. Long run, it is worth the investment because the free programs tend to have bugs and this slows down production, at least I have found it so.